# Dynamic PHP Content to facebook share.php

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

Did a quick search but couldn't find any similar questions/answers. I have a page that dynamically creates content on each load via php.

http://dustri.al/oracle

I am setting the meta tags for description and image via php variables.

The Problem is, when I click the link for fb to share.php, it regenerates the content, so what the user is sharing is not the content/image on the page, but newly generated content.

How can I go about sharing the correct image and description generated on the page?  session? javascript?

Comment: Sharing an address that does not deliver the same content any more when another user visits it makes little sense. As Mathieu said, you should have unique URLs for everything that you want shared, so that the users following the link on Facebook actually get to see the shared content and not something completely different.

Comment: Well it does make sense in this situation. whats important is that the image/content are the same thats generated on the page. Looking into SDKs right now for solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make sure your link is unique on each call. You can pass on a generic timestamp in the URL. If you don't facebook will cache the data and never ask again (or it'll take quite some time before it does) because it doesn't want to spam your server with useless requests that should not change.

For example:

```
http://dustri.al/oracle/20131212-090533-001/
http://dustri.al/oracle/?ts=20131212-090533-001
```

Are a few examples of urls you could use to generate dynamic content on demande. Best would be to associate some kind of unique Id to the content generated and pass it into the url...